# jQuery slider slides randomly

Tags: jquery, css, width

I am basically a PHP coder. Right now I am designing a website for a educational consultancy where I need to add a jQuery slider. The slider I have added have originally have `width:630px`. I needed to fit the slider in a `width:510px;`. For that I have changed the width of the images and the div to 510px. Now the slider is moving randomly when it its kept idle for some time(initially it works fine). [Website with slider](http://7sisters.in/test/) . Please help me as I have beginners knowledge about jQuery.

Comment: try to change some of the css of this slider... `.paging` class i think the pagination is not looking gd...

Answer (score 0):

Well try give nivo slider its a good quality slider, Would be a good idea to look at the demo that they give to see how to setup or copy the html format or look at the documentation.

http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/

The documentation will show you how to setup nivo slider and all the available jquery functions

http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/#/documentation